# Is local circularity an aspect of differentiable functions?

Tags: calculus

I understand that differentiable functions approach linearity at very small scales. But since they never really lose their curvature (excluding linear functions), I was wondering whether their curvature approaches circular arcs at very small scales. It seems that it should not be true, but is there a simple way to prove or disprove this conjecture? I got to thinking about this while considering the mean value theorem and whether the point c approaches the midpoint of the interval as the interval size goes to zero, which I suppose is true for a circular arc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the graph of 2nd order differentiable functions, you can always find an osculating circle. (The flat case is just one with infinite radius).

Comment: Then does this imply that the tangent line whose slope equals the mean slope on [a,b] must intersect at the midpoint of the interval, just as a tangent line to a circle intersects at the midpoint of the arc subtended by a chord?

Comment: That's slightly more complicated unless you are using a moving frame that is rotating with the tangent direction of the curve. Anything different from an actual arc will deviate at an order of $o(h^3)$ where $h$ is the distance away from the tangent point.

Answer (score 1):

A straight line doesn't have a corresponding circle... If you are going around a figure 8 track, most of the time you are circulating around one of two centers, but there is a transition point where you are not circulating anything.

Frequently, we can talk about a "kissing circle" to a curve and the radius of curvature.  But, that radius may not be always be defined as in the examples mentioned.